# How to get only date in group by statement in Linq to sql

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

How to get only date in group by statement in LINQ

```
 var res = query.GroupBy(   b => b.CreatedDate.ToString() ).Select(c => new
                {
                    ShredQueueCount = c.Sum(w => w.ShredQueueCount),
                    ShredCompletedCount = c.Sum(w => w.ShredCompletedCount),
                    ShredValFailureCount = c.Sum(w => w.ShredValFailureCount),
                    ShredExceptionCount = c.Sum(w => w.ShredExceptionCount),
                    CreatedDate = c.Select(w => w.CreatedDate)
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a LINQ expression that will be used by LINQ to SQL at SQL Server end then you need [`EntityFunctions.TruncateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395596.aspx) like:

```
query.GroupBy(b => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(b.CreatedDate.Date))
```

Otherwise for LINQ to objects you can use:

```
query.GroupBy(b => b.CreatedDate.Date)
```

if your field is of Type `Nullable<DateTime>` then you can do:

```
query.GroupBy(b => b.CreatedDate.DefaultIfEmpty().Date)
```

That will ignore the `Time` part in `DateTime` field.

Comment: I'd like to get group by only on date .

Comment: @nimishjain, do you mean just by Date, and not Time ?

Comment: @nimishjain, I have modified the answer you, need: `query.GroupBy(b => b.CreatedDate.Date)`,

Comment: I don't see Date is coming after  b => b.CreatedDate

Comment: @nimishjain, modified the answer for LINQ to SQL. and you don't see date because `CreatedDate` is `Nullable<DateTime>`

Comment: Thank you.  one question , when will I get the Date option on DateTime field

Comment: @nimishjain, for nullable date time, you will neeed `CreatedDate.Value.Date` but make sure to check for `Null` to avoid Null reference exception.